# For the results of either ps aux or ps -ef, how do I just find the commands with brackets?

Tags: ps

So I get the results of

```
root         2     0  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:23 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [events/0]
root         5     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]
root         8     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [async/mgr]
root        44     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [sync_supers]
root        46     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 bdi-default
root        48     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd/0]
root        66     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        67     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        68     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 aio/0
root       185     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/ubda-8]
```

How do I just find the commands with the brackets around them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the following methods print whatever is within `[` and `]` but only if that is the last field:

```
ps aux | awk '$NF~/\[/{print $NF}'
```

The advantage is that it will only match a `[` in the last field. The equivalent using `grep` is

```
ps aux | grep -o '\[.*\]$'
```

You can also do this with Perl

```
ps aux | perl -lne '/(\[.+?\])$/ && print $1'
```

And `sed`:

```
ps aux | sed -n 's/.*\(\[.*\]\)$/\1/p'
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't word it right, I'm trying to print only the results that would fall under the command line that have brackets, I also didn't realize before I need to use a pipe for this.

Comment: @linux8807 I don't understand. Could you [edit] your question and show your desired output? What do you mean the "results that would fall under the CLI that have brackets"? Do you want the line just after those with brackets?

Comment: instead of having 
root        44     2  0 Jan18 ?        00:00:00 [sync_supers]
as a result, I would just want
[sync_supers]
as the result, including all the other results that wuld be in brackets

Comment: I'n entering the command ps -ef. I get results that are in a line like

**root 44 2 0 Jan18 ? 00:00:00 [sync supers]**

I would like to know what command I would need to enter to find just the results under the command line only, how **[sync supers]** is. "Give a command line starting with ps aux that will print only entries with square brackets around the command field of processes currently running."

Comment: @linux8807 ah, OK, see updated answer. However, the sentence you quote (is this homework?) tells you to print _entries_, not just the part within brackets. Anyway, my updated answer prints only the part within the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

What about  `ps aux | grep '['`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the comment by schaiba is the closest.

ps aux | grep ']'

By using the closing bracket it returns all of the lines that end in a square bracket with the rest of the ps aux data.